# JQuery Datatable slow search on custom search function

Tags: jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

I am using `DataTables 1.10.19`. My requirement is to provide search operation based on checkbox selection. i.e is I have checked employee name checkbox then the search will be applied on the employee name only. If I select the location check box, then the search will be applicable to both employee name and location fields. Also, I'm not showing these columns to the user. The search is done on the hidden columns. Everything is working fine as expected, but now I have 2000+ entries and now there is an issue with the performance. Sometimes the browser hangs as well. Is there any other solution rather than ajax based search. My Code is as below.

```
var checkbox_column = {
    //checkbox value to datatable column index
    empname : 2,
    jobtitle : 3,
    location : 4
};

$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(function(oSettings, aData, iDataIndex) {
var filter_val = $('.datatable-search-box:visible').val().trim().toLowerCase();

if (filter_val == '') {
    //no value is inserted
    return true;
}

//apply filter only if checkboxes are selected
if ($('.dt_filter_checkbox:visible:checked').length) {
    var columns_match = [];
    $('.dt_filter_checkbox:visible:checked').each(function(){
        columns_match.push(checkbox_column[$(this).val()]);
    });

    if (columns_match.length) {
        var text_compared = false;
        for (i in columns_match) {
            text_compared = (aData[columns_match[i]].toLowerCase().indexOf(filter_val) !== -1);
            if (text_compared) {
                break;
            }
        }
        //no match found for the data
        if (!text_compared) {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
} else {
    return false;
}
    return true;
});
```

> Code to apply data table and custom filter

```
var data_table = $("#table-employees").dataTable({
    language: {
        search: '',
        searchPlaceholder:'Search',
        sInfo : "<span class='actual_text'>Showing _END_ of _MAX_ records</span>",
        sInfoFiltered : "<span class='filtered_text'>Showing _TOTAL_ of total records</span>",
        sInfoEmpty : "<span class='empty_text'>Showing 0 to 0 of 0 entries</span>",
    },
    'columnDefs': [
        {
            'targets': [0],
            'orderable': false,
        },
        {
            "targets": [2,3,4],
            "visible": false
        }
    ],
    'order': [ 1, 'asc'],
    drawCallback: function(){
        $("img.emp_image").lazyload();
    },
    fnDrawCallback: function() {
        //removing header
        $("#table-employees thead").remove();
    },
    bLengthChange : false,
    "pageLength":   200,
    dom:
    "<'row be-datatable-body'<'col-12'tr>>" +
    "<'row be-datatable-footer'<'pb-3 pb-sm-0 col-auto col-md-auto col-lg-6'i><'col-auto col-md-auto col-lg-6'p>>"
}).on('search.dt',function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        if ($('.filtered_text').length) {
            $('.actual_text').hide();
            $('.empty_text').hide();
        } else {
            $('.actual_text').show();
        }
    },10);
});

$('.datatable-search-box.all').keyup(function() {
    data_table.fnDraw();
});

$(document).on('change','.dt_filter_checkbox', function(){
    data_table.fnDraw();
});
```

**EDIT**

With the default search functionality, there is no compromise with the performance.

Comment: If you can create a fiddle that demonstrate the problem it might be able to figure out. The above is impossible to comprehend :) Here is a starting point -> http://jsfiddle.net/0f9Ljfjr/1975/